# Excel Column Widths from table

Tags: excel, height, width

From a list of columns incl Header names with defined widths in a separate sheet, I want to be able to reset column widths in a named sheet to follow the widths defined in the table, e.g.
Column A - Firstname width 32
Column B - Lastname width 40
Column C - Telephone width 6
Column D - Email width 36 etc

The same could be done to define row heights defined in a similar manner.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe its because im sleepy that im not understanding but you want a way to select a spreadsheet based on its name and just by inserting values, you can define its width from a value in a table from another spreadsheet. Is that it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too imprecise to permit a targeted answer. A variant of the code below may present a generic solution.

```
Worksheets("Target").Columns(12).ColumnWidth = Worksheets("Source").Columns(3).ColumnWidth
```

This code has two parts. On the right, the column width is read. On the left it is set. You can do either with any column that you can specify, including the column of a named range such as you have in a table. You can assign the read value to a variable and apply the width stored in a variable to any column you can specify, including columns of named ranges like in a table or ranges you specify in your code on the fly. Note that the column widths is a numeric value of Single data type.

Note that the *PasteSpecial* method offers an option to copy the column width, too. And, of course, you have the command `AutoFit` at your disposal to adjust a column's width to whatever is needed by its contents.

Comment: Thanks for this. Let me give it a try. I want fixed width, but different from column to column. Got a similar suggestion from another contributor so I'll  try.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the feedback. Chances are that your trials will lead to code and that code is likely to better express your actual needs than the present format of your question. append that code to your question (or ask a new question with your code included) and expect an answer that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for what I understood you wanted.

```
Sub test()

Worksheets("test").Columns("D").ColumnWidth = Worksheets("Values").Range("D4").Value
Worksheets("test").Columns("E").ColumnWidth = Worksheets("Values").Range("D5").Value
Worksheets("test").Columns("F").ColumnWidth = Worksheets("Values").Range("D6").Value

Worksheets("test").Range("D7").Value = Worksheets("Values").Range("C4").Value
Worksheets("test").Range("E7").Value = Worksheets("Values").Range("C5").Value
Worksheets("test").Range("F7").Value = Worksheets("Values").Range("C6").Value

End Sub
```

If you have troubles putting this together with your excel file, I will gladly help you.

Comment: Thanks for this. Very similar to what another contributor kindly sent. It looks right but I am not so good at this. Easier if I could send you a small file to explain.

Comment: @AxelBlom Yeah, you can send me a file